# c# Xamarin SQLConnection still open and i don't know why

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

i have a strange problem with my xamarin ios pcl app.

I have a login mechanism which checks is a sqlserver database is accessable and "if yes" then it downloads some infos from a different database. The iPad is using OpenVPN to create a connection to your network and everything seems to work great except one big issue.

**1. step** 
The OpenVPN connection is diasbled but wifi is available (outside our network). The login method detects that the server is not available and use an another method to login.. great.

**2. step** 
The OpenVPN connection is enabled and the sql server is reachable a´nd everything is again working perfect.

**3. step** 
I disable the OpenVPN connection and logon again. Now the SQLConnection is initialized and the method conn.Open(); is performed. **The connection state is "open" but why? There is no connection to the server available**.

At the first time i thought it could be an issue that the SQLConnection object will not disposed correctly but i can't find any fault. I've checked everything, the server is really not available (used ping app) but the state is already open.

When i restart the App the sate is detected correctly again, which is an indicator that something is keeping in memory which making the sqlconnection object detecting as open.

Can anybody help me to find out why the connection is shown as open after the conenction was opened with openvpn before?

This is the method to check the connection to the sql server:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ADMA2.iOS.SqlServer))]
namespace ADMA2.iOS
{
/// <summary>
/// Steuerung der Datensynchronisierung mit dem SQL Server
/// </summary>
public class SqlServer: ISqlServer
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the Error message if occur
    /// </summary>
    private string error = "";
    public string Error
    {
        get { return error; }
    }

    public bool LoginToSqlServer(string ServerIP,
                                    string Database,
                                    string Username,
                                    string Password) {

        string connectionString = "Persist Security Info=false" +
          ";Integrated Security=true" +
          ";Initial Catalog=" + Database +
          ";Server=tcp:" + ServerIP +
         ";User ID=CONTEX" + @"\" + Username +
         ";Password=" + Password +
         ";Connection Timeout=10";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                conn.Open();
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
}
```

This is the code to check if the server is reachable

```
    public string Login (string Username, string Password)
    {
        try {   

            // many more code here.....

            var mySqlServer = DependencyService.Get<ISqlServer>(DependencyFetchTarget.NewInstance);
            bool isOnline = mySqlServer.LoginToSqlServer(ConfigurationData.GetSQLServerIP(),
                                            ConfigurationData.GetTechUserDB(),
                                            ConfigurationData.GetTechUser(),
                                            ConfigurationData.GetTechUserPassword());


            if (isOnline) {
                    // Many more code here
                }else{
                    // Many more code here
                }

            return "";

        }catch(Exception ex){
            return "Allg. Fehler:" + ex.Message;
        }
    } // login
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're losing the scope rather than closing the connection in your code above. Looking at MSDN's information regarding the use of 'SqlConnection.Open Method()'

> If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it is not closed. Therefore,
>   you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close.
>   [Link to MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would suggest explicitly closing the connection when you are done with it.

Comment: THx. I will check this.